# UEFA/FIFA scores API

Tags: web-services, api, rss

Does anybody know if [UEFA](http://www.uefa.com/) or [FIFA](http://www.fifa.com/) provide a scores api for football matches, official team players list, transfers, etc?

I found [footytube api](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/api_overview.php) but not sure ofits stability and completeness..

Comment: I found your question looking for UEFA/FIFA API and I found the footytube api. Thank you for that reference :)

Comment: So do you use any of this APIs?

Comment: the deleted answer suggested a World cup JSON on Github - that may help.

Comment: If anyone's searching for this in 2018: FIFA has an API which provides a ton of information. The URL for the World Cup is: https://api.fifa.com/api/v1/calendar/matches?idseason=254645&idcompetition=17&language=en-GB&count=100 I couldn't find any documentation (obviously), but the JSON is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: @Christallkeks Thank you~ I 'm looking for this api!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

UEFA or FIFA don't seem to provide any API to get the information you want. However, there are some third-party services which support that:

- [OPTA](http://www.optasports.com/) - Both commercial and free. They have incredible database about matches. Whoscored.com currently uses it.
- Others: livescoreboards, xmlsoccer, ...

Comment: great!, any update on this sites? or new ones ?

Comment: you got any free version? of APIs? for Soccer data?

Comment: ESPN API has been discontinued: http://developer.espn.com/blog/read/publicretirement

Comment: Stay away from xmlsoccer. The customer service is simply non-existent (literally they haven't answered a single support email!). The data is inconsistent, and a lot of fields undocumented. Horrible!

Comment: OPTA looks very nice but is not free though.

Comment: I sued the JSON service on http://livescore-api.com during the world cup. It was nice. Not free, but it was reliable enough to use it in my website and app.

Answer (score 27):

http://api.football-data.org/index is free and useful.
The API is in active development, stable and recently the first versioned release called alpha was put online. Check the blog section to follow updates and changes.

Comment: I have found wrong information being provided by this one. Matches marked as "FINISHED" with a score even though they hadn't happened yet.

Comment: Does it have live scores?

Comment: it provide livescores with a maximum gap of around 1 minute after a goal is scored.

Comment: It has a limit now - practically it's not free anymore...

Answer (score 2):

UEFA internally provides their own ***LIVEX*** Api for their Broadcasting Partners. That one is perfect enough to develop the Applications by their partners for themselves.

Comment: do you have a link!?

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out. In the meanwhile i have these samples: https://match.uefa.com/v1/matches/2027112 , https://comp.uefa.com/v1/competitions/14 . Please post of you have any documentation or documentation hints

Answer (score 1):

You can find stats-dot-com - personally I think their are better than opta. ESPN seems don't provide data in full and do not provide live data feeds (unfortunatelly).

We've been seeking for official data feed providing for our fantasy games (solutionsforfantasysport.com) and still staying with stats-com mainly (used opta, datafactory as well)

Comment: @Sergio - does stats.com have a free developer preview. I couldn't find it on their site.