# Any option to bypass Incapsula protection in python3 while scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, incapsula

I'm new in scraping, and I'm already blocked by the Incapsula protection.

```py
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

page_soup.h1
```

I can't access any data from the website because I'm blocked by the InCapsula problem... 
When I type :

```py
print(page_soup)
```

I get this message:

```py
<html style="height:100%"><head><meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>
[...]
Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 936002200207012991-
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my function 'page\_soup.h1' returning empty result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164404/why-is-my-function-page-soup-h1-returning-empty-result)

Comment: @sentence - That page was removed, for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some tests described here [Getting ‘wrong’ page source when calling url from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36971604/getting-wrong-page-source-when-calling-url-from-python) and only the workaround of [@Karl Anka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3805500/karl-anka) worked out.

See the example below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
driver.quit()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```html
<html class="js flexbox rgba borderradius boxshadow opacity cssgradients csstransitions generatedcontent localstorage sessionstorage" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
 <head>
  <script async="" src="https://c.pebblemedia.be/js/data/david/_david_publishers_master_produpress.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://scdn.cxense.com/cx.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/plugins/inferredEvents.js?v=2.8.47">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/1554445828209863?v=2.8.47&amp;r=stable">
  </script>
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! 
I got the same output as you. Now I need to learn how to extract the different informations from the different real estate property in the pages.

Comment: The thing is, for the moment, tu best to do is to use Selenium and Fake_agent to bypass incapsula

Comment: Also try to use proxies along with selenium. InCapsula using browser fingerprinting techniques also